# How to achieve smooth scrolling on a web page with a lot of images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a lot of images incorporated on one of my pages, Pinterest would be the best thing to compare it to, and I noticed that scrolling especially in Chrome is really jerky and not smooth. Is there a way to achieve smoother scrolling? Would I do this through JavaScript or is it a CSS property?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I think Paul Irish covered something similar to this on Episode 6 (Could be a different Ep.#) of the Break point about fixing a bug on Wikipedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason scrolling on Pinterest is smooth is because of a few things:

1. Images are lazily loaded. They are also probably [cached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) on the server side for faster serving.
2. Images are cleared if they are sufficiently far from the viewport (the images at y=0 should be cleared if you're THRESHOLD pixels down). This clears up memory and provides a smoother experience (this is similar to how a [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) works in iOS).

My suggestion?

1. Cache images on your server.
2. Clear the images that are THRESHOLD pixels away from the viewing port.
3. Lazy load images.
4. [Use a good infinite scroll plugin.](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll)

P.S. - If you are serving really large files (by size), you're going to get a slow experience (depending on how fast your internet connection is).

Comment: For those who don't know what 'lazily loaded' means:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

Comment: @Vinay - what exactly is this technique "Clear the images that are THRESHOLD pixels away from the viewing port."?

Comment: @Brian I am not aware of a library that does it for you (perhaps there is one out there and I encourage you to look), but the general concept would be to bind to the scroll event on window (or whatever view is scrolling) and then capture whether the user is THRESHOLD pixels down. If they are, destroy the javascript objects associated with the views for the first X images. Keep in mind that this means you will have to also recreate these images if the user were to scroll up. Hmm... I may make a library that does this now that I'm thinking about it.

Comment: You can do var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop(); var pageBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(); if ( element .offset().top >= THRESHOLD ) { //Remove element here } else { //Recreate element here }; Or something close.

Answer (score 0):

id' suggest to use js to load all pictures in the visible area of your browser and a bit further and if the user scrolls down then you load some more pictures. scrolling gets really bad when there are to many pictures from the beginning.